# Can I create an instance of a service for every loaded component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I have a component named `edit-order.component` with the following ts file

```
export class EditOrderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private editOrderSrv: EditOrderService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editOrderSrv.getOrderById(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
  }
}
```

and in my `edit-order-service.service.ts` I have the following code

```
export class EditOrderService {
  order$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getOrderById(id: string){
    this.http.get('url', {params: {id}}).subscribe(order => {
      this.order$.next(order);
    }, error => {console.error(error)});
  }
}
```

The client should be able to open more than one `edit-order.component` with different `id`. In my `child.component` I want to subscribe to `order$` like that

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  order: any;
  constructor(private editOrderSrv: EditOrderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editOrderSrv.order$.subscribe(order => {
      if(order) this.order = order;
    })
  }

}
```

But therefore I have to have own instances of the service for every `edit-order.component` to not overwrite `order$`. How would I achieve that? Or is this not possible? And if it is not possible, what can I do else to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why use a separate `BehaviorSubject`? You can just return the observable returned by `getOrderById()`.

Comment: @rveerd For later. I have more than one child component of edit-order.component and I have to store more than one variable in the service for that particular order. Thats why I need different instances to not overwrite variables so that I can access the correct variable for the corresponding order.

Comment: If you are using angular routing, then you may use the same component on the basis of id and also the same service instance. The current implementation seems a bit uncommon to me.

Comment: @Invader I don't think you should store component-specific data in the service. Store it in the component. Use the service just for "services", such as getting data from a webservice.

Comment: If you really need a service per component instance, you might be able to do it using [dependency providers](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-with-components).

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj  I could also use http requests in each child component but I am not quite sure whether it is efficient to always make a http request in each child component. Can you tell me whether it is okay to make few http requests per child component or would it be too inefficient? If it would not be too inefficient it would be a lot easier because the id is not changing troughout route changes (when routing between the child components).

Comment: @rveerd Thank you, I will take a look at it! And yes this is what I want to do. But I can open the component in different tabs with different ids, if I get data from my webserver I would always overwrite the data in my service although they are still needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curiosity, why not your function is

```
getOrderById(id: string){
    return this.http.get('url', {params: {id}})
  }
```

And you subscribe to `getOrderById`?

You can pipe(catchError) if you wish

**Update** you can also use a "cache" in the service without use an array of Subject, only an array of object

```
  orders:any={}  //create an empty object where we store the result

  getOrderById(id: string){
    if (this.orders[id])
        return of(this.orders[id]

    return this.http.get('url', {params: {id}}).pipe(
      tap(res=>{
         this.orders[id]=res;
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: I try to minimize the number of http requests and I need the order in my child components thats why I wanted to call the function once and then always just subscribe to ```order$``` in ever child component in which I need the order else I would have called the function many times in different child components. I wanted to centralize the order somehow. I am not quite sure how many http requests would be okay that is why I try to do everything with as few requests as possible and then use the data in the whole application.

Comment: I update the answer to use a "cache" or orders using `pipe(tap)`

Comment: @Eliseo I also thought about this solution, but, assume that you have 2 components with the same id and when you change data from the first component you will not get notified in the second one.

Comment: ::glups:: you think more deep than I, It's true, in this case not work

Answer (score 1):

It's a really bad idea to create different instances of a service. The purpose of the service is to be singleton and that's how it's designed.
A good way you can use it is to hold a key-value object for every order observable. from parent components pass the `this.route.snapshot.params.id` to the child components as input.
(**Code untested**)

service:

```
export class EditOrderService {
   public orders$: { [orderid: string]: BehaviorSubject<any> } = {};

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getOrderById(id: string): void {
      this.http.get('url', { params: { id } }).subscribe(order => {
         if (!this.orders$[id]) {
            this.orders$[id] = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
         }
         this.orders$[id].next(order);

      }, error => { console.error(error); });
   }
}
```

child component:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  order: any;
  @Input() orderId: any;
  constructor(private editOrderSrv: EditOrderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editOrderSrv.orders$[orderId].subscribe(order => {
      if(order) this.order = order;
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: That is a nice idea, did not thought about this. So I just create an object with the id as a key for every data I want to store for a order. I will try it thanks!

Comment: It's the point that you tough about, but instead of creating service instances you creating BehaviorSubject instances.